# Using a non defined variable in a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi im trying to get the Velocity of a transform, this runs in FixedUpdate. Problem is: lastPos stays at null, is there any way to change lastpos to the value of the last cycle without going outside the method? I need this to be scalable.

```
 void CalculateWing(Vector3? lastPos = null)
    {
        if(lastPos.HasValue == false)
        {
            lastPos = Vector3.zero;
        }
        //This Calculates the Velocity
        Vector3 WingVelocity = (Vector3)((transform.position - lastPos) / Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        //This should save the Position of the last cylcle but is overwritten... 
        lastpos = transform.position
    }
```

Comment: The answer is no, lastPos is confined to the scope of your function. What do you mean by "I need this to be scalable" however? Why can't you have an object that has the value as a member, and update that?

Comment: Im Using this function multiple times in my Physics script, this is of course a way simplified version. I have one CalculateWing function for every wing on my Plane. Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make lastPos a global variable in the script and keep updating that instead of passing it into the function.

lastPos only exists in your CalculateWing function therefore this line:

```
lastpos = transform.position
```

is really only updating the parameter variable here

```
void CalculateWing(Vector3? lastPos = null)
```

and is then effectively forgotten about after that function has executed.

Comment: Thanks, but what if i am using this method for my left and right wing? i want to use different transforms for them. Do i really need to make two methods for my left and right wing?

Comment: In which case you could pass in the transform as a parameter in the function. The best thing to do, is to write the left and right wing functions separately and you'll probably find that other than a variable or two they are the same. You can then start to merge them together and use parameters so you only have the one function.

Comment: Okay i got a solution now, i have a bool in my function that tells if the wing is on the left or right, and therefore i can assign different global variables to one function :)